# Read in and merge many CSV files into data.table

Tags: r, csv, data.table, eval

I have many `.csv` files, containing variables for the same "population", keyed by `surname` and `first.name`.
So every `csv` has three columns: first name, surname and the variable of interest. 
I load each one of them in separate data tables which then I want to merge them.

```
library(data.table)
surnames <- c('A', 'B')
first.names <- c('C', 'D')
weights <- c(80, 90)
heights <- c(180, 190)

write.csv(data.frame(surname = surnames, first.name = first.names, 
                     height = heights), file = 'variable-height.csv')
write.csv(data.frame(surname = surnames, first.name = first.names,  
                     weight = weights), file = 'variable-weight.csv')

variables.to.load <- c('height', 'weight')
for (i in variables.to.load) {
assign(paste0('DT.', i), fread(paste0('variable-', i, '.csv')))
print(dim(eval(parse(text = paste0('DT.', i)))))
setkey(eval(parse(text = paste0('DT.', i))), surname, first.name)
}
```

loads them and sets the keys correctly. 
What I am missing, though, is the automatic merging.

```
DT.merged <- Reduce(merge, list(DT.height, DT.weight))
```

works, but I want to do it in an automatic way, since the real variables are many more. That is, I want to write the contents of `list()`: `DT.height`, `DT.weight`, etc in an automatic way.

I have tried:

```
library('stringr')
DT.merged <- Reduce(merge, list(eval(parse(text = str_c(paste0('DT.', variables.to.load), collapse = ', ')))))
```

with no results.

I do the whole process, because I want to selectively have different variables for my population (which totals to a csv with more than 30GB and around 30 variables). So using `fread` on the full `csv` to selectively read columns seems rather slow.

Comment: Repeat with me: "We do not use `assign` until we become experts in R and need it because we work with environments". `fread` the files into a `list` (easiest with `lapply`). Then you can use `Reduce` on that list.

Comment: At the beginning you say that you have a lot of CSVs to read but at the end you seem to imply that you could open some other file that contains all the columns which would eliminate the tricky part of what you're trying to do.  There's almost no chance that it is faster to open lots of CSVs and merge them instead of opening one csv that has all the data.

Comment: Are you by chance looking for the `select` parameter of `fread`?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor you are correct. I didn't explain this properly. I do this,  because in the course of my analysis, I want to add and remove columns/variables for my DT, for the sake of memory efficiency for my poor laptop, since the original "merged" `.csv` is around 35Gb. Hence, as @Roland suggested, using the very useful `select` in `fread` turns also to be slow, if I need to read one column only.

Comment: @Roland On the `assign` comment:  :) Yes working with lists would be the trick indeed! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for your question

```
DTlist <- lapply(paste0('variable-', variables.to.load, '.csv'), 
    function(x) {
       d <- fread(x) 
       setkey(d, surname, first.name)
       d
     }
   )
DT.merged <- Reduce(merge, DT)
```

That being said, as Roland and I allude to in comments, this is unlikely to be the best approach if you have access to a single CSV file with all your desired data.

If you do have access to such a file you'd be better served to use the `select` parameter of `fread`

```
DT <- fread('master.csv', select=c(variables.to.load))
```

Comment: Thanks! Note for network stumblers: there should be a second parenthesis before the `{`:  `for(i in 1:length(variables.to.load)) {` and also a parethesis less after `fread`: `variables.to.load[i], '.csv'))`.

Comment: Just use `DTlist <- lapply(paste0('variable-', variables.to.load, '.csv'), function(x) {d <- fread(x), setkey(d, surname, first.name); d}); DT.merged <- Reduce(merge, DTlist)`.

Comment: @Roland I edited to your suggestion.  I know everyone hates `for` loops in `R` so I'm sure this will look better.  I was trying to keep the suggestion looking like what OP already had.

Comment: @pidosaurus I believe I fixed the parenthesis too.

Comment: `for` loops are useful if you don't need a return value.