# How to use a dynamic data frame name in a function in R

Tags: r, variables, dataframe

I am creating a dynamic data frame name using system date. The code is as follows.

```
date = Sys.Date()-1
date1 = paste("",date,"",sep="")
titlerepo = paste("GA",format(Sys.Date()-1,format = "%d"),format(Sys.Date()-1,format = "%b"),"AppData",sep="")
```

Here the result I get is titlerepo = "GA03MarAppData".

I use this further down the script to store a value so that it becomes a data frame.

```
assign(paste("GA",format(Sys.Date(),format = "%d"),format(Sys.Date(),format = "%b"),"AppData",sep=""),read.csv(pathapp,header = FALSE,sep = ",",comment.char = "#"))
```

Now I want to use this name and want to perform functionalities that are there for a data frame name like

```
names(GA04MarAppData)[1] = "SN" 
names(GA04MarAppData)[2] = "USWin"
GA04MarAppData[grep("^/p/",(paste("GA",format(Sys.Date(),format = "%d"),format(Sys.Date(),format = "%b"),"AppData$ScreenName",sep=""))),]
```

but I am unable to use it this way.

I have tried the following code but with no success.

```
assign(paste("names(","GA",format(Sys.Date(),format = "%d"),format(Sys.Date(),format = "%b"),"AppData)[1]",sep=""),"ScreenName")

names(titlerepo)[1] = "ScreenName"
names(titlerepo)[2] = "UniqueScreenView"
```

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654357/read-in-and-merge-many-csv-files-into-data-table#comment58990270_35654357 You should change your whole approach.

Comment: @Roland Could not understand the context apart from the fact that append should no be used.

Comment: No, you shouldn't use `assign` (if you don't need to assign to a specific environment). There is pretty much always a better approach.